# Mysql : Table multiple rows Insert into one sql row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I'm creating a software, where i can create multiple row in a table. [image: Purchase Table]

But the why I wrote PHP code, it create multiple rows into SQL but i need to create one row against one invoice number.

Html (auto generate using ajax):

```
<tr>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="product_name[]" value="'.$proData['name'].'"></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control qnt'.$proData['id'].'" min="0" step="any" type="number" name="qnt[]" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control unit_price'.$proData['id'].'" type="number" min="0" step="any" name="unit_price[]" placeholder="Unit Price"></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control pack_size'.$proData['id'].'" type="number" min="0" step="any" name="pack_size[]" placeholder="Pack Size"></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control unit_pack'.$proData['id'].'" type="number" min="0" step="any" name="unit_pack[]" placeholder="Unit Pack (jar/Drum)"></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control total_kg'.$proData['id'].'" type="number" name="total_kg[]" placeholder="Total Kg/s" value="" readonly></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control total_price'.$proData['id'].'" type="number" name="total_price[]" placeholder="Total Price &#2547;" value="" readonly></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="rowDelete btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>
```

php Code :

```
public function add(){
        // Form Inputs
        $invoice = $this->input->post('invoice');
        $date = $this->input->post('date');
        $created_by = $this->input->post('created_by');
        $products = $this->input->post('products');
        $qnt = $this->input->post('qnt[]');
        $unit_price = $this->input->post('unit_price[]');
        $pack_size = $this->input->post('pack_size[]');
        $unit_pack = $this->input->post('unit_pack[]');
        $total_kg = $this->input->post('total_kg[]');
        $total_price = $this->input->post('total_price[]');
        $payed = $this->input->post('payed');
        $price_less = $this->input->post('price_less');
        $price_discount = $this->input->post('price_discount');
        $price_due = $this->input->post('price_due');
        $grand_total = $this->input->post('grand_total');
        $payMethod = $this->input->post('payMethod');
        $bank_name = $this->input->post('bank_name');
        $cheque_no = $this->input->post('cheque_no');
        $bank_acc_no = $this->input->post('bank_acc_no');

        for($i = 0; $i < count($qnt); $i++){
            $purchaseData = array(
                'invoice_no' => $invoice,
                'date' => $date,
                'product_id' => $products,
                'create_date' => $created_by,
                'qnt' => $qnt[$i],
                'unit_price' => $unit_price,
                'pack_size' => $pack_size,
                'unit_pack' => $unit_pack,
                'total_kg' => $total_kg,
                'total_price' => $total_price,
                'payed' => $payed,
                'price_less' => $price_less,
                'price_discount' => $price_discount,
                'price_due' => $price_due,
                'grand_total' => $payMethod,
                'payMethod' => $grand_total,
                'bank_name' => $bank_name,
                'cheque_no' => $cheque_no,
                'bank_acc_no' => $bank_acc_no
            );

            $PurchaseQuery = $this->db->insert('purchase', $purchaseData);

            if($PurchaseQuery){
                $purchaseAdded = "Product Purchase Add.";
                $this->session->set_flashdata('purchaseAdded', $purchaseAdded);
                redirect('Purchase');
            }
        }
    }
```

Please Help. I'm Using CI.

Comment: yes because you are using a for loop to append the data to an array? the qnt must be greater than 1 thus multiple rows are being inserted

Comment: You want to insert multiple data ?Haven't understood the questions to be honest.If you need multiple data use bulk import.Simply INSERT INTO example(ex1,ex1) VALUES('123','123'),('123','123').....

Comment: @Arslan.H if i simply insert i get this "Message: Array to string conversion" error bcoz my table rows are auto generate by ajax every time i select the product. my question is "I've one invoice no & i need to insert all data into one sql row. I mean if purchase invoice same then all product insert same row"

Comment: @Exprator Yes you r right. that's why im asking help.

Comment: can you tell me clearly what you want to do? if you want one row to insert, remove the for loop and then normally insert as you are doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the requirement i quit different . what you can do is ? instead of looping through items . i mean

```
count($qnt)
```

just  json_encode() the multiple items

or change your pattern and normalize you tables
to put order and items of orders in 2 different table

Answer (score 1):

Please do this.

```
public function add(){
        // Form Inputs
        $invoice = $this->input->post('invoice');
        $date = $this->input->post('date');
        $created_by = $this->input->post('created_by');
        $products = $this->input->post('products');
        $qnt = $this->input->post('qnt[]');
        $unit_price = $this->input->post('unit_price[]');
        $pack_size = $this->input->post('pack_size[]');
        $unit_pack = $this->input->post('unit_pack[]');
        $total_kg = $this->input->post('total_kg[]');
        $total_price = $this->input->post('total_price[]');
        $payed = $this->input->post('payed');
        $price_less = $this->input->post('price_less');
        $price_discount = $this->input->post('price_discount');
        $price_due = $this->input->post('price_due');
        $grand_total = $this->input->post('grand_total');
        $payMethod = $this->input->post('payMethod');
        $bank_name = $this->input->post('bank_name');
        $cheque_no = $this->input->post('cheque_no');
        $bank_acc_no = $this->input->post('bank_acc_no');

            $purchaseData = array(
                'invoice_no' => $invoice,
                'date' => $date,
                'product_id' => $products,
                'create_date' => $created_by,
                'qnt' => $qnt[$i],
                'unit_price' => $unit_price,
                'pack_size' => $pack_size,
                'unit_pack' => $unit_pack,
                'total_kg' => $total_kg,
                'total_price' => $total_price,
                'payed' => $payed,
                'price_less' => $price_less,
                'price_discount' => $price_discount,
                'price_due' => $price_due,
                'grand_total' => $payMethod,
                'payMethod' => $grand_total,
                'bank_name' => $bank_name,
                'cheque_no' => $cheque_no,
                'bank_acc_no' => $bank_acc_no
            );

            $PurchaseQuery = $this->db->insert('purchase', $purchaseData);

            if($PurchaseQuery){
                $purchaseAdded = "Product Purchase Add.";
                $this->session->set_flashdata('purchaseAdded', $purchaseAdded);
                redirect('Purchase');
            }
    }
```

and let me know the result.

Comment: Thank You for your ans. But I'm getting error "Message: Array to string conversion". My html input filed name are same "<input class="form-control qnt" min="0" step="any" type="number" name="qnt[]" placeholder="Quantity">" (table row auto generate using ajax).

Comment: can  you share your web site url?

Comment: hi.pls share your website url.

Comment: @美美花 thank you for your help. #Swarna gave me the right answer.